# Migration from Webpack 1 to Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, postcss, css-loader

I'm currently migrating Webpack1 to the second version.
As I saw [here](https://twitter.com/PostCSS/status/611931469691396096),

"Webpack is now using Postcss and cssnano in CSS-loader."

- That means that I don't need to install postcss-loader?
- In my old Webpack.config.js file I have this:

```js
webpackConfig.postcss = [
  cssnano({
    autoprefixer : {
      add      : true,
      remove   : true,
      browsers : ['last 5 versions']
    },
    discardComments : {
      removeAll : true
    },
    discardUnused : false,
    mergeIdents   : false,
    reduceIdents  : false,
    safe          : true,
    sourcemap     : true
  })
];
```

How do I use those options in the new Webpack 2?

Answer (score 2):

You could pass in the 'mimimize' option to css-loader

```
...
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
        minimize: true,
...
```

Comment: I can pass 
{
    autoprefixer : {
      add      : true,
      remove   : true,
      browsers : ['last 5 versions']
    },
    discardComments : {
      removeAll : true
    },
    discardUnused : false,
    mergeIdents   : false,
    reduceIdents  : false,
    safe          : true,
    sourcemap     : true
  } to the options as well?